# Torque and Force of Pulley fixed on side

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, torque, surface-tension

If you had only 1 pulley that is connected to a rotating shaft, and which has a rope circled around it once, with a mass M on one side and with the rope fixed on the other end, how would you then calculate the translate force from the mass to the pulley and thus the torque applied from the pulley on the shaft[image]

Also how would you call such a pulley system ? does anyone know of some uses for this ?

The pulley will turn with the shaft once the motor runs and thus will it have slippage ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show that this system is at *equilibrium* (neither *translational* nor *rotational* motion). I will leave this to you only as a hint. Knowing about *Newton's Second Law* (both in its *translational* as well as its *rotational* versions,) please approach the problem starting with a drawing of *Free Body Diagram* that includes *all* the forces and resultant torques.

Comment: i haven't worked with this for a while so could you specify more about the approach ? i tried what you said but am still confused when it comes to calculating the slippage once the pulley starts rotating, so in theory am getting some of the load off ? as in if i had a 3N force coming from the weights i would have 3N*0.3(estimated mu for friction) ? so the load would be that * the radius(3cm) of the pulley in meters ?